# Error generated when summing rows by month

Tags: r

Below is the data of success vs failure with date and I wanted to sum by month. I tried the following command but it gives the following error

```
rowsum(xx$success, format(xx$$date, "%b-%Y"))
```

> Error in format.default(structure(as.character(x), names = names(x), dim = dim(x),  : 
>    invalid 'trim' argument

Not sure where I am wrong.

```
    date    success
 5-Sep-02       0
19-Sep-02       0
25-Sep-02       1
10-Oct-02       0
12-Oct-02       0
14-Oct-02       1
15-Oct-02       0
28-Oct-02       0
30-Oct-02       0
 9-Nov-02       1
14-Nov-02       0
19-Nov-02       1
 2-Dec-02       0
12-Dec-02       0
16-Dec-02       0
```

Comment: The base equivalent from the existing Q/A for this would be `aggregate(success ~ format(as.Date(date, "%e-%b-%y"), "%Y-%b"), dat, sum)`

Comment: It's not entirely clear whether the question is how to aggregate both success and failures which may be a somewhat more original question. I edited my answer below to reflect this. It would be great if the OP could clarify.

Comment: @Felix if they do I'll flag it for re-open.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `dplyr`:

```
# first convert date to class "date":
xx$date <- as.Date(as.character(xx$date), "%d-%b-%y") # careful: if your locale is not set properly %b might return NAs

xx %>% 
group_by(date = as.yearmon(date)) %>% # we group by month, using as.yearmon from the package "zoo"
summarise(success = sum(success)) # and then we summarise
```

This should result in:

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

      date success
1 Sep 2002       1
2 Oct 2002       1
3 Nov 2002       2
4 Dec 2002       0
```

Your problem was that rowSum does not aggregate by month, but would sum each *row* i.e. each observation. You basically told `R` to sum the month and the success value which (obviously) threw an error.

Edit:

From rereading the question, it wasn't entirely clear whether OP wanted a count of both successes *and* failures in a month. That requires only a little tweak to the code I posted above:

```
df %>% 
group_by(date = as.yearmon(date)) %>% 
summarise(successes = sum(success == 1),
          failures = sum(success == 0))
```